# Registering Payments automatically using python code throws error

Tags: python, odoo, payment, invoice

This is the code that I used to register the payments:

```py
Payment1 = self.env['account.payment'].with_context(default_invoice_ids=[(4, SaleInvoice.id, False)])
payment = Payment1.create({
    'payment_date': SaleInvoice.date,
    'payment_method_id': 1,
    'payment_type': 'inbound',
    'partner_type': 'customer',
    'communication': SaleInvoice.name,
    'partner_id': SaleInvoice.partner_id.id,
    'amount': paymentAmount,
    'journal_id': default_journal_id.id,
    'company_id': SaleInvoice.company_id.id,
    'currency_id': self.env.company and self.env.company.currency_id and self.env.company.currency_id.id,
    'payment_difference_handling': 'reconcile',
    # 'writeoff_account_id': self.diff_income_account.id,
})
payment.post()
```

It throws an error

```
Error: Odoo Server Error

res = self._obj.execute(query, params)   ValueError: <class 'psycopg2.IntegrityError'>: "new row for relation "account_move_line" violates check constraint "account_move_line_check_accountable_required_fields"

DETAIL:  Failing row contains (32465, 7210, null, null, null, null, null, null, 20, null, null, null, 10, Write-Off, 1.000, null, 0.00, 1056.04, 0.00, null, 0.0, null, null, null, f, 2021-04-19, null, 414, null, null, null, 25, null, null, null, null, null, t, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2, 2021-04-21 05:55:09.266162, 2, 2021-04-21 05:55:09.266162, null, null, null, null, null, null).   " while evaluating   'model.paymentSync()'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for 4 hours for this error. Because the same thing happened to me. In this case, when an invoice has outstanding debts and needs to be settled, it makes use of the writeoff_account_id field
Simply send the id of the related object account.account

```
payment = Payment1.create({
   'writeoff_account_id': self.env['account.account'].browse("you id").id,
})
```